# Determine power needs of a motor

Tags: power-supply, motor

I recently stripped a motor out of an *old* 2887-z gaf dual-8 mm projector. I'm not even sure if the motor AC or DC, although I suspect its a brush less ac motor. Unfortunately, I disposed of the connections between the chord and motor without analyzing what they did to the power - although I was under the impression they didn't do much.

I've included images of the motor - there's a large transformer built around the motor.

Q: How do I determine the motor's power needs and characteristics so that I can buy a power supply?

motor images
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIHKT.jpg

user guide
http://www.atsrentals.com/docs/8mm-Projector-Manual.pdf

other:
the motor is very pre-internet age so I am unable to locate specs. but I thought I shoud mention there is a serial number "846-542" paint stamped onto the secondary winding and a "J" "R" stamped on either side of the motor.

Comment: "pre-internet" would mean it isn't BLAC or BLDC. The "transformer built around hte motor looks like the back iron of the stator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The motor looks like a shaded pole AC induction type - very efficient and very quiet. Similar to this one from http://www.indiamart.com/lunar-motors-pvt-ltd/ac-shaded-motors.html - SPM61 series.

[image]

Only question is - what was the AC supply voltage to the projector - 220V or 120V. This is answered in the user guide - 120V, 60Hz.